# Pedal board switching on and off pedals

Tags: effects-pedal

I am thinking of putting together a pedal board and am having trouble trying to configure or plan out how my clean and overdrive channels will work. My hope is that on one of the loops for a pedal switcher, I can loop a reverb and a chorus to always be on during clean; and, also include the overdrive but not be active until I press that channel switch. 
By turning on the O/D pedal, I would like to then have the reverb and chorus turn off.

Is this possible? or would I have to use two loops and press both simultaneously?
Hopefully this isn't confusing. Basically I am looking to switch 3 pedals: 2 off and 1 on. Then 1 off and 2 on via the same channel.

Comment: So you want to have "O/D" as one option, and "reverb + chorus" for the other option? If so, a Boss LS-2 with "O/D" in one loop and "reverb + chorus" in the other should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A/B Switch.  I've done something similar involving a looper.  In your case, if I'm interpreting correctly:

Guitar -> A/B Switch

A -> Rvb/Chor

B -> o/d

New problem:  Two leads, one input on the amp.  I tried all sorts of MacGuyvering (2 -> 1 1/4" adaptors do NOT work) before just buying an 8 track mixer.

A -> Input 1

B- > Input 2

mixer out -> amp

So long as the levels for 1/2 are equal, and you don't mess with them, you should be fine.

A four track mixer, or even a DJ-esque 2 line would be fine, but my gear doesn't move much, and got into "might as well" pretty quickly.  Also, there was a used one at GC for $20.  Done.

There are also direct input devices (http://thehub.musiciansfriend.com/live-sound-buying-guides/how-to-choose-the-right-direct-box), but I've never quite understood them, and don't really have a use for a preamp.

Yet.  Have fun.